# How to detect if get incoming call from a special contact

Tags: android-contacts

i have a Recyclerview in my app that show all the user contacts
which user can select any item(contact) of list
I want when selected contacts call the user the app do somthing i want.
I have all the codes and work perfectly but i just have one problem
in my app when user click on the list item my app save number of contact and when user get incoming call i check if the incoming number is one of the list items which user selected, app do somthing
the problem is if user for example save the number like 0090********** when device is ringing i get the incoming number but incoming number is like +90********** and program doesn't work or maybe user saved number without country code like 0********* and again program doesn't work
what i can to do? any idea?
i know it is possible in all three ways because the phone book detect that contact in any ways all the time but my app don't
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to format **both** the saved phone number in the app, and the incoming call phone into the `e164 format`, this is a canonical format for phone numbers: `+<country-code><phone-number>`.

To do that, you should Google's `libphonenumber` package here:
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Something like this:

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
String formattedNumber = phoneUtil.format(inputNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
```